# Any tool to live patch X.org? I.e., reload X.org without logout and login

Tags: xorg, desktop

I'm trying minimize my number of reboots (it's a desktop Linux workstation), and I've found some nice tools that can reload the kernel without reboot: Oracle [ksplice](https://www.ksplice.com/), SUSE [kGraft](https://www.suse.com/promo/kgraft.html) and RedHat [kpatch](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2014/02/26/kpatch/).

But I was not able to find similar tool to reload X.org without logout and login again when driver update is out.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Would [xpra](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xpra) meet your needs?

Comment: @StrongBad Thank you for you suggestion: I was about to tag my question as `forever-alone`. But as I can see, `xpra` still relies on my `X.org`, so if new drivers are out, I'll need to restart it. Anyway, thank you! :)

Comment: But you should be able to start a new xserver, with patches, on a new display and then detach your applications from the old xserver and reattach them to the new xserver. I have never used xpra, so I don't know for sure.